# Any dialog window in DM that will not block the whole program?

Tags: dialog, dm-script

I would like to know whether there is a kind of pup-up dialog that will not block the whole program. In the following simplified example, the standard deviation of a test image is calculated and then pups up in an OK dialog window.

```
image Img := RealImage("",4,1024,1)
Img = Random()
Img.ShowImage()

number SDev = sqrt(Img.Variance())
OKDialog("Standard deviation =" + SDev)

number Factor
if(!GetNumber("Input the factor that I want:", 5, Factor))
exit(0)
```

Is it possible to move this window aside (since the info within is needed) so that I can still zoom in or zoom out my image for further evaluation?

OkDialog(), ShowAlert(), and OkCancelDialog() all cannot fit my requirement. As well, I am aware of that printing this value in the result window could be an alternative, but I just want to show this info in a more visible dialog window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any dialog derived from `UIFrame` and displayed with the `Display()` method and not the `Pose()` method will do exactly that.

However, when displaying such a modeless dialog your other code will just continue to run. The dialog is on a separate thread.

This is the opposite of a modal dialog which will wait for it to be closed before code execution resumes.

So, if you want a script, that presents a dialog, allow "doing stuff" but then continues when the dialog closes, things are a bit more complicated to do.
You can only do this when you script is on a background thread.

#### Examples:

Simple, blocking, modal dialog:

```c
    clearResults()
    Result("I do stuff \n")
    OKDialog("Wait for me!")
    Result("I continue to do stuff \n")
```

Simple, modeless dialog. Only works for scripts on a background thread:

```c
    // $BACKGROUND$
    
    number ModelessTwoButtonDialog(string prompt, string but1, string but2)
    {
          number sem = NewSemaphore()
          ModelessDialog(prompt,but1,but2,sem)
          Try{GrabSemaphore(sem);}
          Catch{return 0;}
          return 1
    }
    
    clearResults()
    Result("I do stuff \n")
    number res = ModelessTwoButtonDialog("Wait for me!","OK","CANCEL")
    Result("I continue to do stuff. You pressed:" + res)
```

Simple, modeless dialog that will not block your script execution. (But dialog buttons may do stuff).

```c
    class myDlg:UIframe{
          void OnButtonDoStuff(object self) { result("\n Action!"); }
          myDlg(object self)
          {
               taggroup dlg = DLGCreateDialog("My Dialog")
                dlg.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("just text in this dialog"))
               dlg.DLGAddElement(DLGCreatePushButton("DO stuff", "OnButtonDoStuff"))
               self.Init( dlg )
          }
    }
    
    clearResults()
    Result("I do stuff \n")
    Alloc(myDlg).display("Title")
    Result("I continue to do stuff.")
```

Simple, modal dialog that will block your script execution. (But dialog buttons may do stuff).

```c
    class myDlg:UIframe{
          void OnButtonDoStuff(object self) { result("\n Action!"); }
          myDlg(object self)
          {
               taggroup dlg = DLGCreateDialog("My Dialog")
                dlg.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("just text in this dialog"))
               dlg.DLGAddElement(DLGCreatePushButton("DO stuff", "OnButtonDoStuff"))
               self.Init( dlg )
          }
    }
    
    clearResults()
    Result("I do stuff \n")
    Alloc(myDlg).pose()
    Result("I continue to do stuff.")
```

Simple, modeless dialog that will block your script execution until closed. (But dialog buttons may do stuff).
(The script on the main-thread is constantly telling DM to do other stuff as long as the window is open. A bit ugly.)

```c
class myDlg:UIframe{
      void OnButtonDoStuff(object self) { result("\n Action!"); }
      myDlg(object self)
      {
           taggroup dlg = DLGCreateDialog("")
            dlg.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel("just text in this dialog"))
           dlg.DLGAddElement(DLGCreatePushButton("DO stuff", "OnButtonDoStuff"))
           self.Init( dlg )
      }
      ~myDlg(object self){Result("\n Dialog actually removed from memory.");}
}

clearResults()
Result("I do stuff \n")
documentwindow win = Alloc(myDlg).display("Title")
while (win.WindowIsOpen()) doEvents()
Result("I continue to do stuff.")
win = NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using FloatingModelessDialog( String prompt, String buttonName, Number semaphore ) or ModelessDialog( String prompt, String buttonName, Number semaphore )?

http://digitalmicrograph-scripting.tavernmaker.de/other%20resources/Old-DMHelp/AllFunctions.html

Also perhaps the DLG functions might do the trick?

http://digitalmicrograph-scripting.tavernmaker.de/other%20resources/Old-DMHelp/CoreDialogLibrary.htm